# Poco HTTPSClient session by IP address

Tags: poco, poco-libraries

I'm trying to use Poco HTTPS client session to download a site from hostname by specific IP address.
For example, google.com has the following addresses:

- 173.194.221.113
- 173.194.221.138
- 173.194.221.102
- 173.194.221.139
- 173.194.221.100
- 173.194.221.101

I want to get https://google.com via 173.194.221.102

I was trying the following approach:

```
std::make_unique<HTTPSClientSession>(SecureStreamSocket(SocketAddress(IPAddress("173.194.221.102"), 0), "https://google.com"));
```

This fails with the exception "Illegal state: Cannot set the port number for an already connected session"

Looking at the Poco source code, the SecureStreamSocket created with this constructor is connected, and the constructor of HTTPSClientSession tries to set the https port(443), and fails to do that with the already connected socket.

Any better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like that:

```
Poco::Net::initializeSSL();
Poco::Net::HTTPSessionFactory::defaultFactory().registerProtocol("https", new Poco::Net::HTTPSSessionInstantiator);

const Poco::SharedPtr<Poco::Net::InvalidCertificateHandler> certificateHandler(new Poco::Net::AcceptCertificateHandler(false));
const Poco::Net::Context::Ptr context(new Poco::Net::Context(Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, ""));

Poco::Net::SSLManager::instance().initializeClient(nullptr, certificateHandler, context);

Poco::URI serverUri("your address");
Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession* session = Poco::Net::HTTPSessionFactory::defaultFactory().createClientSession(serverUri);
```

Hope it helps.